# Monitor Twilio Voice Call Status

Tags: reactjs, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

I am implementing the `Twilio Programmable Voice` to allow Outgoing calls to phone numbers from my Website.

I want to display a timer after the call has been picked by the client but I  can't figure out how to monitor the status of a call in `React`.

[Twilio Docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/connection) - `.status()` can be used to get the current status of the call.

They have the following endpoint `status()` which can be used but in this case, should I create a function which keeps on checking the status of the call somehow until it reaches the `accepted` state?

Is there a way I can track this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The best way to [track the status of a Twilio Client call](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132267-Tracking-the-Status-of-an-Outbound-Twilio-Voice-Call) at the moment is via the webhook [status callbacks that you can set up in TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-status-callback). This means you need to somehow send the data from the webhook to your client, but it is more accurate than polling.

Alternatively, you could just set up a `setInterval` to check every 100ms, for example, and set your state, cancelling the interval when it is the correct state.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I was thinking of going with `setInterval` initially but I was hoping for a better way and I will look into configuring a status callback webhook. Thank You